# C# XNA and monogame. Is it worth it?

Tags: c#, java, xna, monogame

I've learned I can make C# with XNA compatable with Mac/Linux  through monogame but monogame is a seperately developed from C# so noone knows if they'll keep up with C#'s development?

Is it worth the risk to go with C# or should I play it safe and program in Java for crossplatform compatability?

Comment: This is true of any open-source project. If the team decides to stop supporting it.. then you move onto a different library when you have the time. Even Microsoft products get shelved every now and then.. who's to say they won't announce next week that "C# is now redundant. Introducing CBlunt" (I realise that C# is a bad example given that they are actively pushing new things out.. but you get the idea).

Comment: Are you sure you're going to support your game so long that some features of MonoGame will become outdated and unusable at some point? I'd recommend not to worry about it, unless you're heavily relying on something that changes very often.

Comment: .NET is mostly backward-compatible, and Java isn't much different. How would keeping up with C#'s development be an issue?

Comment: SO is wrong place to make decision if something is good or too risky for *you*. Side note: there is something with your keyboard - BUUUT does not seem to be a word...

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the context in which you're developing:

- MonoGame supports XNA 4, so if you're happy sticking with XNA 4 long-term then you're fine.
- The two languages themselves have various advantages and disadvantages, e.g. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java. There's mileage in going with the one that serves your needs better now, unless you have reason to believe you'll need to keep up-to-date with the latest XNA and maintain your game over time.
- Portability is a good thing (I'm generally in favour), but it's not the be all and end all. Look carefully at whether you actually need your game to be portable.

Also:

- Are you working with others? Which language do they know better? What's their view?
- Do you need to recruit/find more people who have experience with one language or the other? Are there more of one or the other in your vicinity?